# Python: intersection indices numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I get the indices of intersection points between two numpy arrays? I can get intersecting values with `intersect1d`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(xrange(11))
b = np.array([2, 7, 10])
inter = np.intersect1d(a, b)
# inter == array([ 2,  7, 10])
```

But how can I get the indices into `a` of the values in `inter`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You could use the boolean array produced by `in1d` to index an `arange`. Reversing `a` so that the indices are different from the values:

```
>>> a[::-1]
array([10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0])
>>> a = a[::-1]
```

`intersect1d` still returns the same values...

```
>>> numpy.intersect1d(a, b)
array([ 2,  7, 10])
```

But `in1d` returns a boolean array:

```
>>> numpy.in1d(a, b)
array([ True, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True,
       False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Which can be used to index a range:

```
>>> numpy.arange(a.shape[0])[numpy.in1d(a, b)]
array([0, 3, 8])
>>> indices = numpy.arange(a.shape[0])[numpy.in1d(a, b)]
>>> a[indices]
array([10,  7,  2])
```

To simplify the above, though, you could use [`nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy-nonzero) -- this is probably the most correct approach, because it returns a tuple of uniform lists of `X`, `Y`... coordinates:

```
>>> numpy.nonzero(numpy.in1d(a, b))
(array([0, 3, 8]),)
```

Or, equivalently:

```
>>> numpy.in1d(a, b).nonzero()
(array([0, 3, 8]),)
```

The result can be used as an index to arrays of the same shape as `a` with no problems.

```
>>> a[numpy.nonzero(numpy.in1d(a, b))]
array([10,  7,  2])
```

But note that under many circumstances, it makes sense just to use the boolean array itself, rather than converting it into a set of non-boolean indices.

Finally, you can also pass the boolean array to [`argwhere`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html), which produces a slightly differently-shaped result that's not as suitable for indexing, but might be useful for other purposes.

```
>>> numpy.argwhere(numpy.in1d(a, b))
array([[0],
       [3],
       [8]])
```

Comment: So rough, but it works :)
easier in Octave:
[inter indexA indexB] = intersect(A,b)

Comment: in1d and intersect1d are not the same. intersect1d gives unique values, in1d gives all the intersection so this answer does not work all the time.

Comment: @Rik, I guess I disagree. It's true that `in1d` doesn't weed out duplicates, but it shouldn't. It's returning indices, and it would be bad to return only one index from a set of duplicates -- that would be confusing behavior. The question doesn't specify which behavior, so this answer does exactly what it asks for: "get the indices of intersection points between two numpy arrays." If you want to have no duplicates, you have to weed them out beforehand, which is reasonable and expected.

Comment: I see your point, you can use np.unique first or after with return_index=true to give indices then use intersect1d. I interpreted that he wanted unique values because of the code he posted but not sure.

Comment: Anyway I posted code below in case someone needs unique values.

Comment: @Rik, makes sense. I assumed the same thing but (in effect) concluded that inputs would already be unique. Your answer is a good addition, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get unique values as given by intersect1d:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([range(11,21), range(11,21)]).reshape(20)
b = np.array([12, 17, 20])
print(np.intersect1d(a,b))
#unique values

inter = np.in1d(a, b)
print(a[inter])
#you can see these values are not unique

indices=np.array(range(len(a)))[inter]
#These are the non-unique indices

_,unique=np.unique(a[inter], return_index=True)

uniqueIndices=indices[unique]
#this grabs the unique indices

print(uniqueIndices)
print(a[uniqueIndices])
#now they are unique as you would get from np.intersect1d()
```

Output:

```
[12 17 20]
[12 17 20 12 17 20]
[1 6 9]
[12 17 20]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
indices = np.argwhere(np.in1d(a,b))
```

Answer (score 1):

For `Python >= 3.5`, there's another solution to do so

### Other Solution

Let we go through this step by step.

Based on the original code from the question

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(range(11))
b = np.array([2, 7, 10])
inter = np.intersect1d(a, b)
```

First, we create a numpy array with zeros

```
c = np.zeros(len(a))
print (c)
```

**output**

```
>>> [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

Second, change array value of c using intersect index. Hence, we have

```
c[inter] = 1
print (c)
```

**output**

```
>>>[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
```

The last step, use the characteristic of `np.nonzero()`, it will return exactly the **index** of the non-zero term you want.

```
inter_with_idx = np.nonzero(c)
print (inter_with_idx)
```

**Final output**

```
array([ 2, 7, 10])
```

#### Reference

[1] [numpy.nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html)

Comment: If there is something need to be improved, plz let me know

Comment: Could anyone explain the downvote?  I would appreciate :)

Answer (score 1):

As of numpy version 1.15.0 intersect1d has a return_indices option :

```
numpy.intersect1d(ar1, ar2, assume_unique=False, return_indices=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old post but  the `numpy.intersect1d()` has a `return_indices flag`.

```
common, inda, indb = numpy.intersect1d(a,b, return_indices=True)
```

would return with `inda` for indices/position with common values for a, and `indb` for b.

However, it returns the 1st intersection point. For example, if a is not unique and has 4 similar values, the indices returned for a are the first.