# Filtering multiple NumPy arrays based on the intersection of one column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rows, intersection

I have three rather large `NumPy` arrays with varying numbers of rows, whose first columns are all `integers`. My hope is to filter these arrays such that the only rows left are those for whom the value in the first column is shared by all three. This would leave three arrays of the same size. The entries in the other columns are not necessarily shared across arrays.

So, with input:

```
A = 
[[1, 1],
[2, 2],
[3, 3],]

B = 
[[2, 1],
[3, 2],
[4, 3],
[5, 4]]

C = 
[[2, 2],
[3, 1]
[5, 2]]
```

I hope to get back as output:

```
A = 
[[2, 2],
[3, 3]]


B = 
[[2, 1],
[3, 2]]

C = 
[[2, 2],
[3, 1]]
```

My current approach is to:

1. Find the intersection of the three first columns using `numpy.intersect1d()`
2. Use `numpy.in1d()` on this intersection and the first columns of each array to find the row indices that are not shared in each array (converting `boolean` to index using a modified version of the method found here: [Python: intersection indices numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483863/python-intersection-indices-numpy-array) )
3. Finally using `numpy.delete()` with each of these indices and its respective array to remove rows with non-shared entries in the first column.

I'm wondering if there might be a faster or more elegantly Pythonic way to go about this however, something that is suited to very large arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indices in your example are sorted and unique. Assuming this is no coincidence (and this situation often arises, or can easily be enforced), the following works:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array(
[[1, 1],
[2, 2],
[3, 3],])

B = np.array(
[[2, 1],
[3, 2],
[4, 3],
[5, 4]])

C = np.array(
[[2, 2],
[3, 1],
[5, 2],])

I = reduce(
    lambda l,r: np.intersect1d(l,r,True),
    (i[:,0] for i in (A,B,C)))

print A[np.searchsorted(A[:,0], I)]
print B[np.searchsorted(B[:,0], I)]
print C[np.searchsorted(C[:,0], I)]
```

and in case the first column is not in sorted order (but is still unique):

```
C = np.array(
[[9, 2],
[1,6],
[5, 1],
[2, 5],
[3, 2],])

def index_by_first_column_entry(M, keys):
    colkeys = M[:,0]
    sorter = np.argsort(colkeys)
    index = np.searchsorted(colkeys, keys, sorter = sorter)
    return M[sorter[index]]

print index_by_first_column_entry(C, I)
```

and make sure to change the true to false in

```
I = reduce(
    lambda l,r: np.intersect1d(l,r,False),
    (i[:,0] for i in (A,B,C)))
```

generalization to duplicate values can be made using np.unique

Comment: Some commentary; this code should be pretty efficient; the main expense would be in the argsort, in case the first column isn't sorted yet. You may want to precompute this argsort if you are making repeated calls. It should be pretty efficient, but I would imagine that doing such operations in a database system with code tuned for exactly these kind of operations could still be a huge gain, if your datasets are really Big with a capital B.

Comment: This method as assumes the integers in question are unique, otherwise only the first instance of each integer will be returned by `searchsorted`. This is a common use case, primary keys in a database for example, but you should note that in the answer.

Comment: I thought about generalizing to duplicate keys, but I figured it would do more to obscure than to clarify. But you are right, good to make it explicit.

Comment: If the arrays are not sorted you get a computationally less expensive algorithm if, instead of sorting them, and then searching each of them for the intersection, you search the intersection for the values in each array, adding a check that `np.searchsorted` did find a match, e.g. `idx = np.searchsorted(I, B[:, 0]); idx[idx == len(I)] = -1; B[I[idx] == B[:, 0]]` works even if `B` is not sorted.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. searchsorted has complexity O(log(n)) in its first argument and O(n) in its last argument. So yeah, you trade what is typically an O(n*log(n)) for an O(n) this way (though radix sort, or quicksort on nearly sorted data, would be O(n) as well), but assuming that the intersection is a small fraction of the total number of entries, as is likely, you are now doing a searchsort for far more points. I highly doubt this method would come out faster in any real world scenario.

Comment: If the arrays are not sorted, then the algorithm I outline is computationally less expensive for sure, which doesn't mean that it is going to run any faster... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to build an indicator array, or a hash table if you like, to indicate which integers are in all your input arrays. Then you can use boolean indexing based on this indicator array to get the subarrays. Something like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Setup
A = np.array(
[[1, 1],
[2, 2],
[3, 3],])

B = np.array(
[[2, 1],
[3, 2],
[4, 3],
[5, 4]])

C = np.array(
[[2, 2],
[3, 1],
[5, 2],])


def take_overlap(*input):
    n = len(input)
    maxIndex = max(array[:, 0].max() for array in input)
    indicator = np.zeros(maxIndex + 1, dtype=int)
    for array in input:
        indicator[array[:, 0]] += 1
    indicator = indicator == n

    result = []
    for array in input:
        # Look up each integer in the indicator array
        mask = indicator[array[:, 0]]
        # Use boolean indexing to get the sub array
        result.append(array[mask])

    return result

subA, subB, subC = take_overlap(A, B, C)
```

This should be quite fast and this method does not assume the elements of the input arrays are unique or sorted. However this method could take a lot of memory, and might e a bit slower, if the indexing integers are sparse, ie [1, 10, 10000], but should be close to optimal if the integers are more or less dense.

Comment: @Jaime, it's similar to bincount but subtly different. Notice that in the operation, `indicator == n` the indicator value is equal to the number of arrays an integer appears in not the total number of times the integer appears in all the arrays. The equivalent, but IMO more convoluted, code to create the indicator array would look like: `reduce(np.logical_and, (np.bincount(A[:, 0], minlength=maxIndex+1) for A in inputs))`.

Answer (score 0):

This works but I'm not sure if it is faster than any of the other answers:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array(
[[1, 1],
[2, 2],
[3, 3],])

B = np.array(
[[2, 1],
[3, 2],
[4, 3],
[5, 4]])

C = np.array(
[[2, 2],
[3, 1],
[5, 2],])

a = A[:,0]
b = B[:,0]
c = C[:,0]

ab = np.where(a[:, np.newaxis] == b[np.newaxis, :])
bc = np.where(b[:, np.newaxis] == c[np.newaxis, :])

ab_in_bc = np.in1d(ab[1], bc[0])
bc_in_ab = np.in1d(bc[0], ab[1])

arows = ab[0][ab_in_bc]
brows = ab[1][ab_in_bc]
crows = bc[1][bc_in_ab]

anew = A[arows, :]
bnew = B[brows, :]
cnew = C[crows, :]

print(anew)
print(bnew)
print(cnew)
```

gives:

```
[[2 2]
 [3 3]]
[[2 1]
 [3 2]]
[[2 2]
 [3 1]]
```